# pass data from a form to a web server using SOAP and WSDL in php

Tags: php, soap

I am a newbie in SOAP and WSDL..I have to get data from a form and pass it through SOAP to a web server. I have the WSDL adress:  ...how can I achieve this? do I have to make some configuration or install something? please help..I also have a function called:  which in the input takes  the following parameters:

Can you please give some advice or an example?

Comment: Your WSDL is not working for me. provide correct URL or Code here

Comment: this is the WSDL adress:

Comment: given URL is not working for me. More over issue you are facing. Please provide more details, until and unless can't help you

Comment: this is the url I was given from the company where I have to send the data..I don't know much more

Answer (score 1):

your service url not loding for me, this is the soap web methods call in php. check this

```
   $client = new SoapClient("http://www.gerovital.local/extras/server.wsdl");
      $params = array (
            "telefon" => 742209305,
            "cod" => "a4urv6bs",
            "ip" => "192.168.55.78"
    );

    $response = $client->__soapCall('inscriereWeb',array($params));
```

Comment: Otherwise we can generate php class files from your wsdl url by using wsdl2php generator tool and then use of that you can call your service methods

Comment: I edited my question..the problem is that the variable $response is't recognised..what is her role?

Comment: did know about Wsdl2php generator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('inscriereWeb',array($params));
```

instead of

```
$response $client->__soapCall('inscriereWeb',array($params));
```

this assign the return of your webservice call to the variable $response.

You can then use `var_dump($response);` to check the webservice response.

Comment: it gives me this:   string(23) "a:1:{s:6:"status";i:3;}"

Comment: You need to check with the company you work with, what this status means, or check the documentation, if they provide you one.

Comment: i've been told that after sending this, a message should appear if the code is good or is bad..but nothing happens.